# Tweepy get_user() creation time

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get the details of a twitter user using Tweepy get_user() method.
I am able to get username, name, description, location etc. but unable to extract the creation time of user profile.

Here is a snippet from the code

d = api.get_user() 
u = jsonpickle.encode(d) 
user=json.loads(u) 
print user['screen_name']    #works fine 
print user['name']           #works fine 
print user['location']       #works fine 
print user['created_at']     #not intended output, returns {u'py/object': u'datetime.datetime', u'**reduce**': [{u'py/type': u'datetime.datetime'}, [u'B90HGAQKBAAAAA==']]}

Please tell me how to get created_at field

Comment: just found that 
we can use the JSONParser to get ‘raw’ json content: 

api = tweepy.API(auth,parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser())

user = api.get_user(1616792324)

now user['created_at'] returns Wed Jul 24 04:10:04 +0000 2013 as desired

Comment: If you've found an answer, you should post it as an answer to your question, and accept it.